# How to show text box in django

Tags: python, django

**Models.py**

```
class AllUsers(models.Model):
    user_fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    dob = models.DateField()
    user_cv = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
    user_department_id = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    user_FK = models.ForeignKey(User)
    coverletter = models.TextField() //THIS IS TEXT AREA
```

Forms.py:

```
class AllUsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dob= forms.DateField(widget=DateInput()) 
    class Meta:
        model = AllUsers

        fields = ('user_fullname','user_email','dob','user_cv','user_department_id',
                  'coverletter')
```

**PROBLEM:**
[image]

coverletter has text-field but so small to enter any text . why?

Comment: Does the rest of the form render correctly?  Can you show your template code

Comment: the grey triangle suggests it is a textarea (not an input[type=text]) so that makes me think it's a problem with styling/css

Comment: @rockingskier yes that's CSS problem !

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
coverletter = forms.CharField(required=False,
              widget=forms.Textarea(
                # rows and colums of the textarea
                attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify widget for this field. It can be done in model:

```
coverletter = models.TextField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: where to define this in models or form. in forms it is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that is similar to what I have in my forms.py for a textarea. Perhaps it might work for you as well.

```
class AllUsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dob= forms.DateField(widget=DateInput()) 
    class Meta:
        model = AllUsers

        fields = ('user_fullname','user_email','dob','user_cv','user_department_id',
                  'coverletter')

        widgets = {
            'coverletter': Textarea(attrs={'class': '???', 'rows': 5}),
        }
```

I believe the "rows:" declaration is what might make the textarea more visible for you.